# Do I need Federation Authentication if I have a custom STS? If so, why?

Tags: azure, claims-based-identity, federated-identity, acs, ws-federation

If I have a custom Secure Token Service that specifically lists out allowed audiences and checks if the token is coming from one of of those audiences and also checks the thumbprint and issuer of the X509 certificate, do I need WSFederation?

Since my STS is checking that the the token already came from a specific application and was routed through my ACS, aren't I verifying all of the things I need to? I know that Application A sent a request to the ACS which sent a request to Application B all from the custom STS, so where does Federated Identity fit in this picture?

**Edit for clarity:**

Sorry I was a bit unclear in the orignal post. I think the confusion came because I used STS instead of security token handler (Way different things, just a typo).
Application A is a custom login service, which displays the login options for the user,  google/facebook/yahoo/etc. Logging in through these service gets the token from the ACS and returns it to application B, the Relying Party. This RP has a custom security token handler which accepts the token and validates that it is has an audience URI matching application A. It also validates that the issuer was the ACS and the thumbprint matches the one of the cert used to sign the token via the ACS.

This means that theoretically application B knows, that application A was used to login (as it came from that audienceURI) and that the ACS sent the token (as it was the issuer and the thumbprint matches). What I am asking is if federated identity is necessary for application B? What exactly do you gain by using it, if you've already proved where the token came from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your question might need some clarification.

First, you might want to explain specifically what you mean by application A and application B, and how your STS fits in this scenario. Applications don't typically issue tokens, only STSes do. In this sense, ACS doesn't connect applications to each other, it connects relying party applications to third party identity providers.

Second, if you're talking about authentication over the web, and you have a custom identity provider STS that's issuing tokens for ACS, then you're probably already using WS-Federation. If however your token acquisition is not browser based, and you're making back-end HTTP calls to ACS, then WS-Federation is not relevant to the scenario.

Third, from the point of view of the STS, the set of allowed audiences is not about token issuers, it refers to entities that will consume tokens issued by that STS. That is, it's the set of subjects that the STS will issue tokens to. This could be applications themselves, or other intermediary STSes along the federation chain. (ACS for example acts as such an intermediary)

Fourth, when you're validating the issuer's certificate on an incoming token, you must do more than just compare the thumbprint. The thumbprint is not part of the token's cryptographic proof. You must validate the token's digital signature in order to verify that the token issuer owns the private key of the certificate.

I hope this clears things up, but if it doesn't answer your question please let me know.

Comment: As per your fourth point, I was using Bertocci's example here:
blogs.msdn.com/b/vbertocci/archive/2008/11/26/an-identity-provider-and-its-sts-writing-a-custom-sts-with-the-october-beta-of-the-geneva-framework.aspx

which makes it seem like all you need to do is verify thumbprint and issuer.

Comment: Ah. The article is a bit dated, and it should be noted that as Vittorio himself says in the post, the example is only for demonstration purposes, it's not production ready. It's not a big deal though because you shouldn't need your own custom security token handler, WIF today already offers some built in security token handlers that will perform proper X509 certificate signature verification for you.

Comment: "WIF today already offers some built in security token handlers that will perform proper X509 certificate signature verification for you"
That may be the case but, I didn't want to have configuration in web.config that was site specific. As such, to remove the audience URI tags I needed to override the default security token handlers. I have taken your advice and looked up proper verification in other places though and added that to my code. I still could use advice on whether federated identity is necessary though.

Comment: Federation would not be necessary if application A did not rely on a third part identity provider (yahoo/facebook/google...etc) as it does in your scenario (through ACS). What federation gives you is the flexibility to have your users sign in using the IDP of their choice. Your specific federation model using ACS also relieves your application B from the burden of having to validate the google/facebook/yahoo tokens themselves, which are different. ACS does this for you, and provides application B with the same kind of token regardless of identity provider, and with a normalized set of claims.